# Is there a way to rejuvenate an old bottle of Gorilla glue?

Tags: adhesive, storage, chemicals

I have a fairly large (2 oz) bottle of "Original Gorilla Glue" which has been sitting on the shelf. I used it once or twice occasionally, but now it has gotten somewhat hard and crystallized and won't come out of the bottle.

I bought the big size with the nice cap hoping it would last for dozens and dozens of projects, and indeed the bottle is still like 95% full. But it's all stuck inside. Is there any way to re-liquefy or soften Gorilla Glue?

Perhaps there's some solvent that evaporated away which I can replace? (Water is probably a non-starter, since that is what typically **activates** it.) Did it just somehow crystallize more like honey and perhaps heating it would turn it back to a liquid I could squeeze out? Or are these bottles just meant for busy builders who would use it all within a few weeks/months?

Comment: now you know not to buy the big bottle of that type of adhesive unless you have a big job that will use it up in a few months.

Answer (score 3):

You are out of luck. Gorilla Glue is a polyurethane glue. Like most modern glues, it cures chemically rather than drying out or setting by cooling. Unfortunately, yours has cured in the bottle.

Other than the obvious tip of putting the cap back on tight when you're done, I haven't found any effective way to keep Gorilla Glue for a very extended period.

Answer (score 2):

It is funny that you ask this because exactly this happened with my dad's Gorilla Glue this past Wednesday.  Nothing came out.  When I took the cap off the top of the glue was hard.  But I could squeeze the bottle.  When I squeezed hard enough I cracked the hard glue and underneath it was still liquid.  The hard glue in there meant we could not use the squeeze top.  We fished out liquid glue from the bottle with an old chopstick.

I have also had Gorilla glue that solidified all the way down.  The bottle was hard.  That glue was done.

Comment: Good point that you can still sometimes rescue some. I have also heard a tip of storing the bottle upside down so that the "crust" forms away from the the tip. But I have had bad experiences with the glue leaking through the cap, making a mess.